# Expected value of Dirac measure: $E[\delta_{\tau}(t)]$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, dirac-delta

Thx for the efforts! I tried to clean up the question and remove the ambiguous notations. For the dirac measure, I use the one found in the Wikipedia article.

I try to formally understand a statement found across literature (as @Did pointed out, assuming independence):

$E[\mathbb{I}_{[0,T]}(\tau)D(\tau)] = \int_{0}^{T}E[D(t)]dP_{\tau}(t)$.

To derive it, the authors do the following:

$E[\mathbb{I}_{[0,T]}(\tau)D(\tau)] = E[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{I}_{[0,T]}(t) D( t) d\delta_{\tau}(t)] = E[\int_{0}^{T} D( t) d\delta_{\tau}(t)] = E[\int_{0}^{T} D( t) \delta_{\tau}(t)dt]$.

And then, what I don't get, they do the following (which might be a notational mess):

$\int_{0}^{T} E[D(t)] E[d\delta_{\tau}(t)] = \int_{0}^{T} E[D(t)] P(\tau \in [t,dt]) $

There are two questions

1. How does the distribution of $\tau$ enter the picture, i.e. what is the relation of $\delta_{\tau}$ to $P_{\tau}$, to get the proposition (1st equation) from the second equation? (MickG's explanations).
2. What is going on with the third equation? Which is hopefully resolved after answering the first question:-) Maybe, the authors mean something like $E[\delta_{\tau}(t)] = E[\mathbb{I}_{[t,dt]}(\tau)]=P(\tau \in [t,dt])$...

Thx!

Comment: First problem with this is that $\delta$ is a measure, not a function, hence what does $\delta(t-\tau)$ even mean? It is not a random variable, in any case, hence $E(\delta(t-\tau))$ seems to be an ill-formed expression. Please explain.

Comment: I added the context to the question. Might be that it is a misuse of notation...

Comment: Everything in the "context" you added makes sense -- except the last identity, I am afraid. What the authors are trying to say is that, under the independence hypothesis you mentioned, $$E[\mathbb{I}_{0 < \tau \leq T} D(0,\tau)] = \int_{0}^{T} E[D(0,t)] dP_\tau(t),$$ where $P_\tau$ denotes the distribution of $\tau$. This holds in full generality, whether $P_\tau$ has a density or not.

Comment: First, thx a lot for your patience!:-) I do highly appreciate it. I edited the question again based on your first remark regarding that dirac delta is a measure...

Comment: Let me take this one step back from your last equation chain, i.e. $E[\int_0^TD(t)d\delta_\tau(t)]$. That would be (assuming $\tau$ is a random variable on $(\mathbb{R},P)$ with $P$ being some probability measure with density $f$):

$$E\left[\int_0^TD(t)d\delta_\tau(t)\right]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_0^TD(t)d\delta_\tau(t)dP(\tau)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_0^TD(t)d\delta_\tau(t)f(\tau)d\tau.$$

What we would like to do is swap those integrals, of course. But the measure in the inner integral depends on the outer integral's variable, making the swap rather tricky. (continues…)

Comment: (… continued) My guess (but it's only a guess) is that we can swap the integrals by substituting $d\delta_\tau(t)d\tau$ with $dtd\delta_t(\tau)$. Let's see what comes out of this:

$$E\left[\int_0^TD(t)d\delta_\tau(t)\right]=\int_0^T\int_{\mathbb{R}}D(t)f(\tau)d\delta_t(\tau)dt=\int_0^TD(t)f(t)dt,$$

which is what you aimed for, right? So once we prove that integral swapping thing, this question is answered, I guess.

Comment: Looking on it again, I'm starting to doubt… can someone chime in and explain how the last expression is reached? We have $\int\int_0^TD(t)d\delta_\tau(t)dP(\tau)$, $P$ being the distribution of our random variable. How do we turn it into $\int_0^TE[D(t)]dP(t)? I believe this will answer the question, @Did. And then maybe we can reopen it and actually post an answer.

Comment: At the moment, there is a notation problem with this damn delta function, which messes things up every time it appears :).

Comment: Thx for your feedback. I (hopefully) removed all the ambiguous notations. The notation of the delta measure follows the corresponding Wikipedia article, i.e. $\delta_{x}(A) = \mathbb{I}_{A}(x)$. Also, what I should add to the question is $D(\tau,r)$, where $r$ is a random variable as well...But I don't think that this really changes the nature of the derivation due to the independence assumption between $\tau$ and $r$.

Comment: Sorry but I am not following why you continue to wax about this on and on. What is there left to understand once (if I may) you take into account my comment? Yes the notations in your question are sloppy, but what these actually mean is clear. Or, is the problem that you do not know what the *distribution* of a random variable is? Here, $P_\tau$ is the unique measure $\mu$ such that, for every suitable $g$, $$E(g(\tau))=\int_0^\infty g(t)d\mu(t).$$ Apply this to $$g(t)=E(D(t))\,\mathbf 1_{0<t<T}.$$ Once you get this, you can forget the horrific notions of $E(d\delta_\tau(x))$ and the like.

Comment: @Did I tried that and I got a different thing that what is purported by the authors… see answer.

Comment: @MickG I do not understand how you "tried that" if "that" refers to what I actually say.

Comment: @Did: Yes, thx, this makes perfect sense for me. I just wonder why the notion with the dirac delta is common...

Comment: Depends on the authors. Physicists like it very much while mathematicians tend to use it more carefully (and more rigorously, I would say, but obviously I am biased on this...).

Answer (score -1):

On the RHS I get $\int_0^\infty E[D(t)]\mathbb1_{0<t<T}d\mu(t)=\int_0^TE[D(t)]d\mu(t)$. On the LHS, I get $E[E[D(t)]\mathbb1_{0<t<T}]$. So:

$$\int_0^TE[D(t)]d\mu(t)=E[E[D(t)]\mathbb1_{0<t<T}].$$

Seems we have one $E$ too many on the right… If I consider $D(t)\mathbb1_{[0,T]}(t)$ instead, I get:

$$E[D(t)\mathbb1_{[0,T]}(t)]=\int_0^\infty D(t)\mathbb1_{[0,T]}(t)d\mu(t)=\int_0^TD(t)d\mu(t).$$

Now there is a missing $E$. So the question I ask is: is the identity stated in your reference actually correct? Also, that integral of $E[D(t)]$ leaves me wondering whether $E[D(t)]$ actually depends on $t$. After all, it is an expected value, so why should it depend on anything? With that, I would have that the first equality has LHS equal to $P([0,T])E[D(t)]$.

Let us now look at how your authors derive their identity:

\begin{align*}
E[\mathbb{I}_{[0,T]}(\tau)D(\tau)] ={}& E\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{I}_{[0,T]}(t) D( t) \delta(t-\tau)dt\right] = E\left[\int_{0}^{T} D( t) \delta(t-\tau)dt\right] ={} \\
{}={}& \int_{0}^{T} E[D(t)] E[\delta(t-\tau)]dt = \int_{0}^{T} E[D(t)] P(\tau \in [t,dt]).
\end{align*}

I restored the "$\delta$ function" since this is just a formal trick to convince readers of the equality. Let us try to see this formal derivation step by step:

1. Introduce the $\delta$ function to express evaluation as an integral;
2. Collapse the indicator into the integration bounds;
3. Bring the $E$ in (it is, at the end of the day, an integral, so you can surely swap it with $\int_0^T$, right?), then assume some sort of independence between $D$ and $\delta$ to turn $E$ of a product to a product of $E$; now this is very sloppy;
4. A very big problem; It seems they assume $E[\delta(t-\tau)]=P(\tau\in[t,dt])$; why is that? And what does that probability even mean? After all, infinitesimal are out of standard analysis, so what is $dt$? They are probably thinking of having $\tau$ very close to $t$; or, they may be thinking of approximating the $\delta$ function with some more treatable function; if $\delta$ is 0 everywhere except $\delta(0)=\infty$, we can see $\delta(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\mathbb1_{[-\frac1n,\frac1n]}(x)$; so $\delta(t-\tau)=\lim_nn\mathbb1_{[-\frac1n,\frac1n]}(t-\tau)$; assuming limit and integral swap, $E[\delta(t-\tau)]=\int\delta(t-\tau)d\mu(\tau)=\lim_n\int n\mathbb1_{[-\frac1n,\frac1n]}(t-\tau)d\mu(\tau)=\lim_nnP(\tau\in[t-\frac1n,t+\frac1n]$; now $\tau$ has a density, and we know the density is the derivative of the cumulative distribution function, so since $P(\tau\in[t-\frac1n,t+\frac1n])=F_P(t+\frac1n)=F_P(t-\frac1n)$, where $F_P$ is the CDF, we get precisely $f(t)$ as that expected value of the $\delta$.

To better (but always formally) treat the third step, we may assume Fubini-Tonelli works fine and try this:

$$E\left[\int_0^TD(t)\delta(t-\tau)dt\right]=\int_0^\infty\int_0^TD(t)\delta(t-\tau)dtd\mu(\tau)=\int_0^T\int_0^\infty\delta(t-\tau)d\mu(\tau)D(t)dt,$$

then we have that inner integral, and, if $d\mu(\tau)=f(\tau)d\tau$, we know that is $f(t)\mathbb1_{[0,\infty)}(t)$, and we are there.

I hope this answers your question. Though that identity in your reference seems incorrect, as I pointed out at the start considering two different functions.

Comment: "On the LHS, I get $E[E[D(t)]\mathbb1_{0<t<T}]$" If "the LHS" refers to the LHS of $$E[\mathbb{I}_{[0,T]}(\tau)D(\tau)] = \int_{0}^{T}E[D(t)]dP_{\tau}(t)$$ I fail ro see how you can get this. To begin with, you suggest a quantity depending on $t$ while the LHS does not depend on $t$. (Relatedly, I suggest to omit the misleading "Doing what @Did's last comment suggests" and similar occurrences later on in your answer.)

Comment: @Did I meant the LHS of: $$E[g(\tau)]=\int_0^\infty g(t)d\mu(t),$$ with $g(t)=E[D(t)]\mathbb1_{0<t<T}$. As in your last comment.

Comment: If I substitute that $g$ into the LHS, I get $E[E[D(t)]\mathbb1_{0<t<T}]$, right? And in the RHS I get $\int_0^\infty E[D(t)]\mathbb1_{0<t<T}d\mu(t)$, right? So I should get: $$E[E[D(t)]\mathbb1_{0<t<T}]=\int_0^\infty E[D(t)]\mathbb1_{0<t<T}d\mu(t)=\int_0^TE[D(t)]d\mu(t),$$ right?

Comment: And you think that with this function $g$, $E(g(\tau))$ is what you said? You seem to be confusing $g(t)$ and $E(g(\tau))=\int_0^\infty g(t)dP_\tau (t)$.

Comment: @Did I fail to see why that is not $E[g(\tau)]$. Could you explain?

Comment: Once again: $E(g(\tau))$ is a **number** while $g(t)$ is a quantity **depending on** $t$, hence the identity $E(g(\tau))=g(t)$ (with which $t$?) is **absurd** (to go to the most obvious).

Comment: @Did what is $E[g(\tau)]$ with that $g$ then? And I completely fail to see any trace of such an (I agree, absurd) identity in my equalities above!

Comment: Please see previous comments, here and on main.

Comment: My RHS does not depend on $t$. Does this really reduce to changing $t$ to $\tau$ in the LHS? Is: $$E[g(\tau)]=E[E[D(\tau)]\mathbb1_{0<\tau<T}]=\int_0^\infty E[D(t)]\mathbb1_{0<t<T}d\mu(t)=\int_0^TE[D(t)]d\mu(t)$$ what I should be writing?

Comment: The RHS of $$\int_0^TE[D(t)]d\mu(t)=E[E[D(t)]\mathbb1_{0<t<T}]$$ does not depend on $t$? Ha. // OK, maybe I should say this: I plan to leave your next contributions to this page, if any, unanswered since 1. I did my best to underline the basic flaws in your answer and 2. I find difficult enough to dispel the OP misconceptions without having also to debunk yours. Sorry.